# Visual C# - Properties.Settings won't save correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, numericupdown, settings.settings

I'm making a program that saves the Mouse X and Mouse Y coordinates from a NumericUpDown-Box into Settings.settings so the program launches with the last used values.

Both Input Boxes call the method "saveXY" when "ValueChanged" [as seen here](http://s14.directupload.net/images/140907/s6l3gbxc.jpg)

My Problem is: the X coordinates get saved without problems, the Y coordinates don't get saved at all - but the code is the same:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        movetoX.Value = Settings.Default.mouseX;
        movetoY.Value = Settings.Default.mouseY;
    }
```

-

```
    private void saveXY(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.mouseX = (int)movetoX.Value;
        Settings.Default.mouseY = (int)movetoY.Value;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Theese are my [Settings.settings](http://s1.directupload.net/images/140907/9roe4ndx.jpg).

The .exe is availeble [here](http://workupload.com/file/C6FSEuiA).

Comment: What do you mean wont' save?
Do you run you app from visual studio?

Comment: I press Strg + F5 to run it, mouseX gets saved in Settings.settings but not MouseY, here's the .exe for testing: http://workupload.com/file/C6FSEuiA

Comment: I see that you update your UI from another thread.I'm not sure why your don't get an exception.Don't use the Thread class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to hamix, its working now

i deleted saveXY and wrote this:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.mouseX = (int)movetoX.Value;
        Settings.Default.mouseY = (int)movetoY.Value;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

it now saves X and Y

Answer (score 0):

This article may be useful to you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> Update 1:

**Had to perform a Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade() and then your saved settings get loaded.**

> **Sample**

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   //Load saved settings

   this.Location = Properties.Settings.Default.Form1Location;
   this.Size = Properties.Settings.Default.Form1Size;
   //Allow changes to be implemented

   this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
   //capture changes

   this.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(Form1_LocationChanged);
   this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(Form1_SizeChanged);
   //capture the closing form event to save your new settings

   this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosed);
}
void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Capture the new values

   Properties.Settings.Default.Form1Location = this.Location;
}
void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Capture the new values

   Properties.Settings.Default.Form1Size = this.Size;
}
void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   //you can capture the new values here as well    
   //save the new values

   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: my one values saves, but my other values doesnt save :/
 -- 
and i dont know why